# Disturbing Notification

Tags: email, wifi

I received an E-mail notification a couple of days ago welcoming me for signing onto Stockholm Arlanda Airport's wifi network.  My wife and I have never been to Stockholm.  I asked my neice's husband who is involved with IT about it and he didn't seem too concerned.  Felt someone might have mistakenly entered my E-mail address when signing on.  Figured I should double check in case.  Anything to be concerned over?  Any recommended security precautions?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: "someone might have mistakenly entered my E-mail address when signing on" or the guy just put any email he knew to access the airport internet.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the comment; this doesn't sound like an issue to me. If the email legitimately came from Stockholm Arlanda Airport (you can check the email address*) and if the email doesn't ask for any personal information, I wouldn't worry.

I don't like putting my personal email address in captive portals; I don't want be on their email list for something I likely don't care about. I suspect that's what happened here - someone simply typed in your email instead of their own.

*Note, most modern email providers do filter spoofed emails, and the probability that's the case is low.